# importing parts of html file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have three files and I want to include/import their content one after another, and construct a single html file.

header.html

```
<header>
Hello, this is a header of the web page.
</header>
```

main.html

```
<main>
Hello, this is a main part of the web page.
</main>
```

footer.html

```
<footer>
Hello, this is a footer part of the web page.
</footer>
```

The expected output:

```
<header>
Hello, this is a header of the web page.
</header>
<main>
Hello, this is a main part of the web page.
</main>
<footer>
Hello, this is a footer part of the web page.
</footer>
```

Is it possible to achieve this in a simple and readable way using xslt?
I have seen lots of xml merge examples and they never satisfied and looked overly complex.
All I want is join the html/xml files into a single file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of XSLT you're running, so I'm assuming just version 1.0.

It can be as easy as:

```xml
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <head>
    <title>importing parts of html file using xslt</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('header.html')"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('main.html')"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('footer.html')"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the stylesheet does nothing with its input document; all it does is explicitly include the three named files into a single template. However, you do have to apply this stylesheet to *some* input document, and since it doesn't really matter which, you can apply the stylesheet to itself.

NB this uses the ["simplified stylesheet"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#simplified-stylesheet) syntax in which your stylesheet is a literal result element (`html` in this case) which is treated as if it were the child of an `xsl:template` that matches `/`.

If I were doing this with an up-to-date XSLT interpreter (i.e. for XSLT version 3.0) I would probably write a stylesheet with a single template named `xsl:initial-template`. This would mean you wouldn't have to supply an input document at all.

e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xsl:version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>importing parts of html file using xslt</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('header.html')"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('main.html')"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('footer.html')"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would write `<body><xsl:copy-of select="doc('header.html'), doc('main.html'), doc('footer.html')"/></body>` because I value brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to parse/process proper HTML using an XML tool chain since HTML isn't XML but uses features from SGML (= original markup language on which XML is based) that weren't included in the XML subset, such as tag inference and other shortforms. There's a tutorial I wrote to accomplish almost exactly what you want using SGML available at [sgmljs.net - Producing HTML](http://sgmljs.net/docs/producing-html-tutorial/producing-html-tutorial.html), though.

That said, XML *does* have entities, so the basic technique of including text fragments via entities to produce XHTML (= XML-conformant serialization of HTML markup) works with any XML parser that does DTD processing, which all of the well-known mature ones do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
  <!ENTITY header SYSTEM "header.html">
  <!ENTITY main SYSTEM "main.html">
  <!ENTITY footer SYSTEM "main.html">
]]>
<html>
  &header;
  &main;
  &footer;
</html>
```

where `&header;`, `&main;`, and `&footer;` are replaced by the respective content of the `header.html`, `main.html`, and `footer.html` files without the need of XSLT or other programming language.

To render the document (given the name `doc.xhtml` here) with expanded text for `header`, `main`, and `footer`, you can use eg. `xmllint` (part of libxml2):

```
xmllint -noent doc.xhtml
```

Be aware, though, that the document produced that way isn't commonly accepted as HTML, and isn't even XHTML proper since it lacks a `head`, `body`, and `title` element (as also observed by @Conal Tuohy), so the minimal *proper* XHTML document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
  <!ENTITY header SYSTEM "header.html">
  <!ENTITY main SYSTEM "main.html">
  <!ENTITY footer SYSTEM "footer.html">
]]>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Importing parts of XHTML using entities</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    &header;
    &main;
    &footer;
  </body>
</html>
```